# Clipboard.SetText() is not working after uploading it online

Tags: asp.net, sql

```
public void myMethod(string test)
    {
        string mytext = "DataGridViewHitTestType"; // the text u want to copy
        Clipboard.Clear();//Clearing the clipboard
        Clipboard.SetText(test);
    }

    public int copycodetoboard(string copy)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(() => myMethod(copy));
        t.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
        t.Start();
        return 1;

    }
```

I am calling the `copycodetoboard("")` function in button click

It's working fine in local, but after uploading it's not working

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

First I like to note you this: I believe that you did not have confuse the server side and the client side run - and I hope to not expect to copy it to the clipboard on code behind, and paste it to your client word program.

Now the `Clipboard` is part of the User Interface, and connected with the logged in user.

Now when you run it locally and debug it, the pool that is running it, is probably run with your account, but when its on server the pool is running as service without access to the desktop and to the user interface, and so the clipboard is not available.

Find some other way to "store" temporary your data and move them around. The clipboard is not the place for an online web application.

Comment: then can any one please  tell that how to copy the copy the code to clip board of client for all browsers

Comment: @lucky If you try to make client copy to clipboard, then you can't For security reasons this is not permitted. Do it manually (select and copy). There are some alternative tricks, google it "cross browser clipboard copy via javascript" and find them.